# Elasticsearch Nested Query into Java API

Tags: java, api, elasticsearch

I was new to Elasticsearch and Java. I was trying to convert a nested elasticsearch query which has both MUST and SHOULD functions. Can someone help on this.

```
GET /list/_search
{
  "size": 12,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "city hed",
                  "type": "bool_prefix",
                  "fields": [
                    "cityName":"",
                    "countryCodeName":"",
                    "iso":""
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "city hed",
                  "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                  "fields": [
                    "cityName*"
                    ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "iso": ""
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "iso": ""
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

need method logic for it like how it will be in Java API

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java High Client try this:

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("idx_name");
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

MultiMatchQueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders
    .multiMatchQuery("city hed")
    .type(Type.PHRASE_PREFIX)
    .field("cityName")
    .field("countryCodeName")
    .field("iso");

MultiMatchQueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder2 = QueryBuilders
    .multiMatchQuery("city hed")
    .fuzziness("2")
    .field("cityName*");

MatchQueryBuilder matchQuery01 = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("iso", "");
MatchQueryBuilder matchQuery02 = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("iso", "");

BoolQueryBuilder bool01 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(matchQueryBuilder).should(matchQueryBuilder2);
BoolQueryBuilder bool02 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(matchQuery01).should(matchQuery02);

BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(bool01).must(bool02);

searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);

searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

SearchResponse searchResponse = getClient().search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Can't we do it without using var ?